# Open-WRT toolchain build machine

Tags: c++, openwrt, toolchain

When I try to build one project I am getting the following error.

> Please build on a Open-WRT toolchain build machine

What this means? How to fix this issue? If the answer may be very long please provide some links to get some idea about this.

I am very new to Open-WRT.

Comment: It seems that you did not install [cross-compilation toolchain](https://wiki.openwrt.org/about/toolchain) for Open-WRT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the OpenWrt Build root https://wiki.openwrt.org/about/toolchain
This will have the openwrt tool chain
Modify the `Makefile` of your application to use the OpenWrt Tool chain.
Basically override the `CC` and `LD` fields (CXX also if it is a C++ application).

```
CC=<path to toolchain>architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc
LD=<path_to_toolchain>architecture-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld
```

More details in the link: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile